# How is a functions of multiple parameters to be interpreted?

Tags: haskell

Given the following function

```
multThree :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a  
multThree x y z = x * y * z
```

and this description of it:

> What really happens when we do `multThree 3 5 9` or `((multThree 3) 5) 9`? First, 3 is applied to `multThree`, because they're separated by a space. That creates a function that takes one parameter and returns a function. So then 5 is applied to that, which creates a function that will take a parameter and multiply it by 15. 9 is applied to that function and the result is 135 or something. Remember that this function's type could also be written as `multThree :: (Num a) => a -> (a -> (a -> a))`.

I interpret this as follows and want to be sure that this is correct:

```
((multThree 3) 5) 9 =
((3*y*z)5)9 =
(15*z)9 =
15*9
= 135
```

Is this the correct interpretation of `multThree`'s functionality as described in this paragraph?

Comment: It is known as Currying. https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying

Comment: I think talking about currying here is more confusing than helpful. Especially since currying is converting a function taking a tuple to a new function taking a single argument, but there is no tuple here.

Comment: All functions are already curried in Haskell. You don't really see the difference until you *uncurry* a function. `uncurry multThree ::  (a, a) -> a -> a`.

Comment: (The combination of currying and the right-associativity of `->` is what lets you informally treat `multThree` as a function of three arguments, rather than a higher-order function that returns a function.)

Answer (score 6):

You are close but you miss a crucial point. `((3*y*z)5)9` is not a valid expression. In particular, while `multThree` in `multThree 9` is a function, `3*y*z` (the thing you substituted `multThree` with) is no longer a function. (Note also that `y` and `z` are used without being defined). To fix the problem we will rewrite `multThree` as

```
multThree = (\x -> (\y -> (\z -> x * y * z)))
-- or dropping all the unnecessary brackets
multThree = \x -> \y -> \z -> x * y * z
```

Now you can substitute and all works out:

```
multThree 3 5 9
= (\x -> \y -> \z -> x * y * z) 3 5 9
= (\y -> \z -> 3 * y * z) 5 9
= (\z -> 3 * 5 * z) 9
= 3 * 5 * 9
```

This might also raise another question about the order of evaluation of the multiplication operator `(*)`. In our case `(*)` is [left associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770118/how-does-the-infix-work):

```
Prelude> :info (*)
class Num a where
  ...
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
    -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
infixl 7 *
```

That is, your `3 * 5 * 9` actually is `(3 * 5) * 9`.

Comment: functions are opaque so there's probably no substitution in the lambda body. (of course this is all just for illustration, who knows how it is actually compiled). personally, I like showing this with the `let`-based re-writes: `multThree 3 5 9 = (\x -> \y -> \z -> x * y * z) 3 5 9 = let {x=3} in (\y -> \z -> x * y * z) 5 9 = let {x=3} in let {y=5} in (\z -> x * y * z) 9 = let {x=3} in let {y=5} in let {z=9} in x * y * z = let {x=3} in let {y=5} in let {z=9} in 15 * z = let {x=3} in let {y=5} in let {z=9} in 135 = 135`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the lambdas, otherwise your interpretation is correct:

```
((multThree 3) 5) 9 =
((\y z -> 3*y*z)5)9 =
(\z -> 15*z)9 =
15*9
= 135
```

In fact, `multThree 3` is the function that expects `y` and `z`, and returns `3*y*z`. We write that as `\y z -> 3*y*z`.

Similarly `multThree 3 5` is the function that expects only `z` and returns `3*5*z`. We write that as `\z -> 3*5*z`.

Finally `multThree 3 5 9` is no longer a function, `3*5*9`.